# jQuery UI Datepicker show current week on load

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

After implementing datepicker, I am able to show `Week picker` using [this](http://tikalk.com/incubator/week-picker-using-jquery-ui-datepicker). But in addition to this I even want to show the current week range on load.

When user clicks on any date, it shows the week range but how can I show current week range onload as well ?

For example, if user clicks on `Nov 2` it shows the week range `Nov 2 - Nov 8` but not showing the current week range which is `Oct 26 - Nov 1` by default onload.

The below function shows the current week start and end date, but how can I show it on load without onselect.

```
var showCurrentWeek = function() {

        var defaultStartDate = $('#startDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate( 'M d', startDate));
        var defaultEndDate = $('#endDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate( 'M d', endDate));
        alert(defaultStartDate.text());
        alert(defaultEndDate.text());
    }
```

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably other ways to do this, but here's one. Simulate a click on the current date by adding this code:

```
$(function() {

    ......

    $(".ui-datepicker-current-day").click();
}
```

Comment: Onclick it shows the start/end date of a week but i need to display the start/end date of current week on page load without any click on datepicker.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy So the display of the start/end date will be completely unaffected by the Datepicker?

Comment: Not really, onpage load show the current week start/end date and if user clicks on any other date of any week, show that weeks start/end date, which is currently working.